# What can I use for brainstorming?

Tags: software-recommendations

[There's already a question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/499/what-software-is-available-for-keeping-and-organising-notes-about-your-world/506#506) about organizing huge amount of information, but for putting concepts together, like a puzzle (or a tree), I could not find anything useful or simple.

When it comes to analyze considerations and getting new ideas, what kind of softwares can we use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

definitely use mindmaps. Written on paper or in computer. Definitely worth to check is Mind Meister (free online tool in browser) or installed software like Xmind http://www.xmind.net.

In mind maps you can easily organize all aspects of comprehensive problems or projects. Handwritten are cool but hard to edit. Therefore I recommend to use comuputer nad projector.

Comment: XMind was good for some time, but when I wanted to use again recently, it was really uncomfortable.

Comment: I personally often use FreeMind (http://freemind.sourceforge.net/) but ymmv

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer having they in front of me, physically. So I'd recommend writing/typing out brief explanations of your concepts. Just a few lines each, that can fit on a piece of card/paper maybe the size of your hand. One concept per card. Print them out and arrange them in front of you (maybe 10 cards per row, work your way from left to right, and downwards), then when you're happy with the arrangement, number them in pencil. Maybe best to worst, or in chronological order, etc. So it's easier if you need to move things around in future, then you can just change the numbers. This way, after you're done arranging and numbering, you can just sweep them up and keep them in a stack, without worrying about forgetting the order. As you formulate your ideas, go through the concepts one by one.

Comment: Of course, if you'd rather do this on soft-copy, that would be ok, I guess, but I find it much easier to have the hard-copy in front of me. Easier to move things around and number them. But then again, I don't always have access to soft-copy stuff