# Which wiki or any other software do you advice?

Tags: software-recommendations

Sorry guys, I have to ask this question. I will close it when I found the "Holy Grail" for my project.

Long story short:
I want to "wikisize" my worldbuilding project, and I tried dokuwiki and mediawiki. Mediawiki was a pain in the ass (sorry) and I struggled with it and I didn't liked it. Dokuwiki was the exact opposite: easy to start with it and it has nice UI. But when it reaches to a decent project size it drastically slows down (becouse it stores the pages in .txt files and not in DB)

Which wiki or software do you advice?

I'm a webdeveloper with some sys-admin skills so setting up a new program wouldn't be difficult.

Comment: I doubt it's really worldbuilding specific. Also, as written now it is purely opinion based. No clear criteria for answers.

Comment: This question would be better suited for SoftwareRecommendations SE

Comment: Right, what you ask is not specific for Worldbuilding, so far as you explained.  See [this Question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/45467/software-website-for-public-world-design).

Comment: framework is part of world-building process, which might have its own specific which is may be more clear to people who try to do the world-building, thus I think it is on-topic, because general sited may just not understand the specifics.

Comment: This is on topic based on content but is off topic on its form.  Without specific criteria for what functionality the software should have we can't answer it and any answer would be opinion based.  Software recommendations are on-topic here (when properly written)

Comment: [See this](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/461/software-recommendations)

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for something local, maybe [TiddlyWiki](http://tiddlywiki.com/)?  That saves everything as individual .html pages, and then you just browse it like a normal website.

Answer (score 2):

If you like DokuWiki you could simply set cachetime to 0 (never expire) instead of the default one day.

Also, remember to verify it is not a server issue. (You did not mention where you have the wiki set up, so have to mention this.)

Comment: Also, maybe should have mentioned this in the answer, but when I had a similar issue it turned out to be due to the file IO on the server being c**p.

Comment: DokuWiki should _not_ become noticeably slower at reasonable sizes. If your installation is slow you should really try to find out why and fix that. Thanks @VilleNiemi for spotting the missing "not".